# Counts of 'Close votes' and 'Reopen Votes' are not accurate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The image below shows the current number of close votes and re-open votes for two questions on the main site.

[image].

As you can see the first question shows that it has 2 close votes and the second one shows one re-open vote. But, when you actually look at the questions themselves you see that the first question has 3 votes to close and the second one has no votes to re-open. Is this a bug?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the date range you have selected -- there are votes olde than the 2 day range you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

The statistics on the meta pages always seem to lag those on the parent pages.  Evidently they are not updated immediately.  (You might have noticed that your reputation when viewed on the meta pages often is a little lower than its current value, too.)

Comment: Yes, there is a delay for some statistics but I suspect that there is no delay in the case of 'actionable' numbers or at least they should not be so that mods and others can take the correct action.